# ios attributed string is not aligned right

Tags: ios

I am developing an app in which i have align some part of text to left and other part to right on same line

Below is my code:

```
    //text is "abc\n"
    NSString *dateAndText = [text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@",strDate]];
        dateAndText = [dateAndText stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];

        CGSize size = [dateAndText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(220, 9999) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;

     NSRange range = [dateAndText rangeOfString:[dateAndText substringFromIndex:text.length]];
        NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:dateAndText];
        [string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:10.0 ] range:NSMakeRange(range.location,range.length)];

        NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init] ;
        [paragraphStyle setAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];

        [string addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(range.location,range.length)];
label.attributedText = string;
```

Attributed string is not aligning right on same line. Please someone help me if i am wrong anywhere in my code

Output should be as below image
[image: output should be in this format]

Comment: where do you assign the attributed text to the label ? What do you want to align right ? A paragraphStyle only works for a whole paragraph .. not for just a few words within a paragraph.. you can't align only a part of a line right.

Comment: what to use to align part of a line?

Comment: label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight will align whole content to right but what i need is to align part of content to right. I used a text(nsstring) variable where it receives "abc\n" as string and then i will append date(12:30AM) to text. Now i have to show "abc" on left and "12:30AM" on right.

Comment: @Vidhyanand900, add some image of the output you want.

Comment: i added image of output i want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `paragraphStyle.lineHeightMultiple = 0.001;`solved my issue.